# Where do I pass my argument to call my function and make my API work?

Tags: python-3.x, api

#my current dictionary
Ranking_dict = dict(zip(dataframe['visitor_id'],zip(dataframe['visit1_exh'], dataframe['visit2_exh'], dataframe['visit3_exh'],
dataframe['visit4_exh'], dataframe['visit5_exh'])))

#Created a local host
#app = Flask(**name**)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def Visits(UserID):
print(Ranking_dict[UserID])

if **name** == '**main**':
app.run(port=2222)

#output should return the values assigned to the key called in the function when UserID is posted

Answer (score -1):

can you use better formatting and explain your problem a little better?
you can add code blocks by typing the following

```py

some code

```

result;

```py
some code
```